# Rendering empty space in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Please see the snippet below. I am trying to render a blinking text, that, when it does not appear, leaves an empty space. However, React is just removing the element all together it seems. How do I properly render an empty space in React? Tried to do some searching and testing with various spans but still didn't get anywhere. Thanks.

```js
class Blinker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      appear: true
    }
    this.blinker = this.blinker.bind(this);
  }

  blinker()  {
    this.setState({appear: !this.state.appear });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.blinker, 1000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.blinker);
  }

  render() {
    const name = "testing";
    const underScore = "_";
    const com = "com";
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="test"> { name } </div>
        <div id="test">
          { (this.state.appear) ? underScore : ' '}
        </div>
        <div id="test"> { com } </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<Blinker />, app);
```

```css
#test {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: you can't have three "test" ids on the page

Comment: What if, instead of adding or deleting the text as you are at the moment, you add or remove `style="display:none;"` on the div?

Comment: @SaidKholov You can. You just really, really shouldn't.

Comment: well applying styles like this wouldn't work `#test {
  display: inline-block;
}` @PaulHicks

Comment: Yep it wouldn't, which is why you shouldn't do it. But you _can_ do it.

Comment: add width to your element. or instead use `visibility: hidden ` when removing it

Comment: seems to work this way: `<div id="test" style={{width:".5em"}}>
          { (this.state.appear) ? underScore : ''}
        </div>`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use `<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>`:

```js
class Blinker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      appear: true
    }
    this.blinker = this.blinker.bind(this);
  }

  blinker()  {
    this.setState({appear: !this.state.appear });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.blinker, 1000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.blinker);
  }

  render() {
    const name = "testing";
    const underScore = "_";
    const com = "com";
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="test"> { name } </div>
        <div id="test">
          { (this.state.appear) ? underScore : <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>}
        </div>
        <div id="test"> { com } </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<Blinker />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
#test {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried <span>&nbsp;</span> before, now I know!

Comment: what if we are trying to render a value that stored in a variable (and that variable is read-only and contains extra space)? Seems to me like it removes the extra space right away after rendering (happened to me while working). It drives me crazy because I can't even change the value (coming through props).

Answer (score 8):

It is because the three nested lines get transpiled as individual children of the parent div element, without taking the spaces into account. Solution is putting a space explicitly between the elements:

```
<div>
    <div id="test"> { name } </div>
    {''}
    <div id="test">
          { (this.state.appear) ? underScore : "\u00a0\u00a0"}
    {''}
    </div>
        <div id="test"> { com } </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you probably have indeed done this intentionally, but can you explain the effect of `{''}` (i.e. emitting a zero length string) (e.g. as opposed to `{' '}` which I think would definitely emit a space)?

Answer (score 4):

I generally use `<Fragment>&nbsp;</Fragment>`, and programmatically render it as many times as I want. The following is another similar usage of 3 different special characters intended to be embedded.

```
import './rating.css'

let starMap={
  '1': <Fragment>&#xe033;</Fragment>,
  '0.5': <Fragment>&#xe032;</Fragment>,
  '0': <Fragment>&#xe031;</Fragment>
}



export default class Rating extends React.Component {
  constructor(ops) {
    super(ops)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <span className={'score'} style={{marginRight: '7px'}}>
          <span className={'star'}>{starMap[1]}</span>
          <span className={'star'}>{starMap[1]}</span>
          <span className={'star'}>{starMap[1]}</span>
          <span className={'star'}>{starMap[1]}</span>
          <span className={'star'}>{starMap[0.5]}</span>
        </span>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
class Blinker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      appear: true
    }
    this.blinker = this.blinker.bind(this);
  }

  blinker()  {
    this.setState({appear: !this.state.appear });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.blinker, 1000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.blinker);
  }

  render() {
    const name = "testing";
    const underScore = "_";
    const com = "com";
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="test"> { name } </div>
        <div id="test">
          { (this.state.appear) ? underScore : "\u00a0\u00a0"}
        </div>
        <div id="test"> { com } </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<Blinker />, app);
```

```css
#test {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tested it, but it should work.

```js
<div id="test" style={{ visibility: this.state.appear ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}>
  {{underScore}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use styled components and I've created an `<Em />` component:

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const Em = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  width: ${({ size = 1 }) => size}em;
`

const App = () => {
  return <h1>I need<Em size={.5} />a half space</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a hard time remembering this `&nbsp;`, You can instead use:

```
<span> </span> // <- this is inline empty space
```